# Почему два раза пишется datetime?

Tags: python, время, datetime, импорт, модули

Добрый день я совсем новичок в программирование можете оябснить что озночате этот код

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.today()
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print(a)
print(b)
```

Почему два раза пишется datetime?

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3):

`datetime` — это встроенный объект в одноименный модуль `datetime`.
Методы `now()` и `today()` находятся в объекте, а не в "корне" модуля.
[source code of module](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/datetime/datetime.py)

```
Help on module datetime:

NAME
    datetime - Fast implementation of the datetime type.

MODULE REFERENCE
    https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime
    
    The following documentation is automatically generated from the Python
    source files.  It may be incomplete, incorrect or include features that
    are considered implementation detail and may vary between Python
    implementations.  When in doubt, consult the module reference at the
    location listed above.

CLASSES
    builtins.object
        date
            datetime
        time
        timedelta
        tzinfo
            timezone
```

Comment: Зачем тут кусок исходника модуля?

Comment: @mkkik Чтобы понять структуру автору, ну и так для увесистости.

Comment: `python -c "import datetime; help(datetime)" | head -22` - может, ограничиться выжимкой?

Comment: @mkkik ok.......